# Refactoring techniques for Clojure

Tags: refactoring, clojure

I'm familiar with refactoring fairly large code bases in C# and Java but Clojure is something of a different beast, especially since it:

- Has a mix of macros and functions in typical code (i.e. you might want to refactor from a macro to a function or vice-versa?)
- Uses dynamic typing in most circumstances (so you don't get compile time checks on the correctness of your refactored code)
- Is functional rather than object-oriented in style
- Has less support for refactoring in current IDEs
- Is less tolerant of cyclic dependencies in code bases (making it harder to move blocks of code / definitions around!)

Given the above, what is the best way to approach code refactoring in Clojure?

Comment: You do like asking the hard questions ;) perhaps Clojure is too young for good answers to this to have developed? is three years enough?

Comment: How is this achieved in similar, more established languages such as Common Lisp or Scheme?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In ["Working effectively with legacy code"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131177052) Michael Feathers suggests adding unit tests to create artificial "inflection points" in the code that you can re-factor around.

a super brief and wholly incomplete overview on his approach to adding order to unstructured code:

- devide the code into "Legacy" (without tests) and the rest.
- create a test
- recur on both halves.

The recursive approach seemed to fit well with the mental processes I use in thinking about Clojure so I have come to associate them. even new languages can have legacy code right?

This is what I got from my reading of that one book while thinking about clojure. So I hope it is useful as a general guideline. perhaps your codebase already has good tests, in which case you're already beyond this phase.

Comment: interesting - what sort of thing would you establish as an inflection point? would this be a namespace, a group of related functions or something like that?

Comment: An inflection point is anywhere there is a seam which allows you to hook into the legacy code.  This could be an interface (if you are lucky), a class hierarchy, namespace/package (i.e. with java, drop in a different jar), etc.  Anything which allows you to encapsulate logically the body of code you want to refactor.

Answer (score 8):

I'm not an expert. But anyway:

- Stay away from `God` functions. If you have a big function, break it down to smaller functions and each of these functions is doing one thing, and it is doing it well.
- If you find usage of Java arrays (and it is not necessary to use them), convert them to Clojure sequences.
- Embrace `defrecord` and `defprotocol`.
- Stay away from macros unless you really can't proceed without writing a macro.
- When it is possible, favor lazy sequences over recursion.
- When creating a service, put the contract in its own namespace and the implementation in its own namespace.
- Achieve dependency injection as passing functions as parameters to another functions.
- Use desctructuring for a function's arglist when it is possible. It will lead to an easier to understand a function's implementation.
- Consider using Prismatic Schema project.

Also, have a look at CursiveClojure. I think it is really promising.

*I'm not the creator of CursiveClojure.*

Answer (score 1):

I'm *not* familiar with refactoring fairly large code bases in C# or Java, but here goes.

Clojure:

- *Has a mix of macros and functions*: I could be wrong, but I think you'll find that refactoring seldom moves the *interface* between macros and functions.
- *Uses dynamic typing (so you don't get compile time checks on refactored code)*: ... nor on any other code: you need more tests in either case.
- *Is functional rather than object-oriented in style* Refactorings are stated in OO terms, but often survive simple transcription: method to function, class to function or closure or map.
- *Has less support for refactoring in current IDEs* True: more busywork.
- *Is less tolerant of cyclic dependencies in code bases* Two cases: mutual recursion in a namespace/file should be easier to cope with than it is; but cyclic dependencies between namespaces/packages cause confusion and ambiguity. I think Java only allowed them because C++ did, and C# followed suit.

I have found it useful to look through Martin Fowler's [catalogue of refactorings](http://refactoring.com/catalog/). Most survive translation from OO to functional lingo. Some (such as [Change Value to Reference](http://refactoring.com/catalog/changeValueToReference.html)) disappear.